# How can I find words in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have lot of queries like this,

> select categorych0_.category_id as category3_2_0_, categorych0_.id as
>   id1_2_0_, categorych0_.id as id1_2_1_, categorych0_.category_id as
>   category3_2_1_, categorych0_.check_id as check_id4_2_1_,
>   categorych0_.tenantid as tenantid2_2_1_, check1_.id as id1_5_2_,
>   check1_.check_group as check_gr2_5_2_,
>   check1_.check_group_description_label as check_gr3_5_2_,
>   check1_.check_group_label as check_gr4_5_2_, check1_.check_name_label
>   as check_na5_5_2_, check1_.check_number as check_nu6_5_2_,
>   check1_.check_scope as check_sc7_5_2_, check1_.display_order as
>   display_8_5_2_, check1_.tenantid as tenantid9_5_2_ from
>   category_checks categorych0_ left outer join checks check1_ on
>   categorych0_.check_id=check1_.id where categorych0_.category_id=?

I need to remove 'as' phrases that mean, all **alies phrases** need to remove.

Comment: Does this work? https://regex101.com/r/TSvUUi/1

Comment: i think this will work: as\s+\w+

Comment: Thanks, @shaunhusain, It is working for the expression  `as (\w+)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
as[^,]*?(?=,|from)
```

Replace each match with a blank string

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/APcmJb/1)

**Explanation:**

- `as` - matches `as` literally
- `[^,]*?` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character that is not a `,` as few as possible
- `(?=,|from)` - positive lookahead to validate that the above match must be followed by a `,` or the text `from`

[image]